# SASS doesn't translate into CSS correctly

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to create a basic website and I want to use SASS to write some CSS. I am trying something really simple at first to understand how it works. However even this simple example doesn't seem to work. Here is the SASS code:

```
    %aParagraph {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
    }



    .specificParagraph {
        @extend %aParagraph;
        font-size: 34px ;
    }
```

but then when it translates into CSS it becomes:

```
    .specificParagraph {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold; }

    .specificParagraph {
        font-size: 34px; }
```

when I actually expected the CSS file to mention aParagraph as well as specificParagraph.

What's going on?

Comment: hmmm.. i suspect `%` is not permitted as a class character.

Comment: What are you expecting `%` to do? I'm confused.

Comment: yep - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/which-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names-selectors

Comment: but here https://sass-lang.com/guide it shows that that is the character to use? I0m confused as well!

Comment: Read the documentation for placeholder selectors: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholders - your expected results don't seem to line up with how this `%className` works.

Comment: You have to write @extend before %aParagraph, I think.

Comment: From the documentation, OP's code is correct. The doc uses `%message-shared {
  padding: 10px;
}`

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this output.

Comment: @JeremyThille The documentation uses `%message-shared` *with `@extend`*.

Comment: it seems to work if I use the dot instead of %. This is well confusing. I will git it another look as I'm very new to all this.